# Change wallpaper with registry without logging off?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, desktop-customization

I have created an application that will change the Windows Registry as below:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] "Wallpaper"="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\wallpaper.jpg"

However, for these changes to take effect, the user must log out and login again. Is there any way to make the wallpaper change with having to do this? Or does anyone know how to change the wallpaper instantaneously with C#?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414635/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-programatically) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net/1061682#1061682). I don't know how "instantaneous" that would be.